# does dtruss under OS X give consistent results when tracing java?

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks, dtrace

I'm new to developing on OS X, coming from a more Linux oriented background.
I was having issues with a java application, so decided to grab a system call trace to see what it was doing. I got inconsistent behaviour when using dtruss for the application.

Going a step further, I then narrowed it down to most simple case I could think of, using a Java HelloWorld which writes using System.out.println:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo java HelloWorldApp 2>/dev/null
Hello World!
bash-3.2$ sudo dtruss -f java HelloWorldApp 2>dtruss.out 
bash-3.2$
```

The app is behaving differently when run through dtruss -- or I'm making a mistake in the way I'm using dtruss / capturing the output from dtruss.

I tried another quick test on a linux box using OpenJDK 7, which behaves as I would have expected:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo java HelloWorldApp 2>/dev/null  
Hello World!
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo strace -f java HelloWorldApp 2>strace.out
Hello World!
vagrant@precise64:~$
```

Is dtruss reliable for grabbing systemcall traces on OS X in all circumstances, e.g. for Java?

Is there an obvious mistake in my dtruss command + output capture above?

Edit:

OS X 10.9
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Edit 2:

Running in a root shell rather than as sudo has same results:

```
bash-3.2# java HelloWorldApp 2>/dev/null
Hello World!
bash-3.2# dtruss -f java HelloWorldApp 2>dtrace.out
bash-3.2#
```

Answer (score 3):

(If I could find a "strike-through" option I would have crossed out the whole of my original answer, so I'm replacing it instead.)

A workaround for the problem you're seeing is to start your `java` process and attach `dtruss` to it after it starts.  In a root shell, type

```
# dtrace -qwn 'proc:::exec-success /execname=="java"/{trace(pid);stop();exit(0)}'
```

Elsewhere (as any user), run your process:

```
$ java HelloWorld

[1]+  Stopped                 java HelloWorld
$
```

You'll see that the `dtrace` command has printed a pid and exited.  Attach `dtruss` with

```
# dtruss -f -p <pid> 2> dtruss.out
    PID/THRD  SYSCALL(args)          = return
```

Now start the `java` process:

```
$ kill -CONT <pid>
```

Comment: I gave this another try, this time running on a root shell, but with similar results. I've added an edit to original post with info.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The method above should allow you to get what you want.  I don't know if the difference in behaviour is because java is being traced or if it's being run with a different environment.